# Windows 8.1 Recovery issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

question title probably duplicate but I have different issue

My PC upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 before Windows allows us to buy the Windows 8 upgrade. I chose to upgrade to Windows 8 buy buying a key then I downloaded the desktop application because that will be used to download the upgrade so and so on. We all came here.

My Windows got a lot of updates and now using Windows 8.1 Pro 6.3, build 9300
[image]

on this very Monday, I decided to just Reset my Windows from original settings, like reinstalling everything and starting up again.

My problem is this
[image: where do I get this?]

**where do I get this?**

Comment: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reset-or-refresh-windows-8-without-dvd/

Comment: You need a Windows 8.1 installation media you should make one a Windows 8 disk won't work for [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media)